# Could not locate column in row for column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm a new user to SQLAlchemy, and following the tutorial on their site.
I ran their tutorial on adding information to databases and querying against a virtual db (sqlite in memory).

After I thought I got that, I tried testing against a real db - mysql db. 
I'm using the `pymysql` driver version 0.4 (I know it's kinda old, but when was using a newer version I had other bugs, not related to this topic).

My code is as follows:

```
def read_from_DB():
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://***@***/test', echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session=Session()

    #insert = CpuTable(id='15',name= 'igal')
    #session.add(insert)
    #session.commit()

    print()
    print(str(session.query(CpuTable.id.label('id')).all()))


    for cpu_id,cpu_name in session.query(CpuTable).all():
        print(cpu_id,cpu_name)
```

my stack trace is as follows:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe J:/working_dir/TLM/lib/DB_Wrapper/Lab_DB/DB_Reader.py
2014-02-12 11:23:57,193 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2014-02-12 11:23:57,193 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-02-12 11:23:57,196 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'
2014-02-12 11:23:57,196 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-02-12 11:23:57,198 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2014-02-12 11:23:57,198 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-02-12 11:23:57,199 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2014-02-12 11:23:57,199 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT cpu.id AS id 
FROM cpu
2014-02-12 11:23:57,199 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 69, in __getitem__
KeyError: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Label object at 0x0000000003C6FDA0>
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:/working_dir/TLM/lib/DB_Wrapper/Lab_DB/DB_Reader.py", line 39, in <module>
    read_from_DB()
  File "J:/working_dir/TLM/lib/DB_Wrapper/Lab_DB/DB_Reader.py", line 26, in read_from_DB
    print(str(session.query(CpuTable.id.label('id')).all()))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2264, in all
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 75, in instances
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 75, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 74, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3440, in proc
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 71, in __getitem__
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.9.0-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 317, in _key_fallback
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'cpu.id'"
```

When debugging this issue, I managed to find out that I do get the result from the db, only if the query was `select table.id` it returns as `table_id`.   (I talked with some friends using this, and they confirmed it happens on their hand as well, only their SQLAlchemy wrapper knows how to handle with this, while mine throws this error). The commented-out `insert` lines are to check I had connection to the db, and also to check it inserts the data, and it does, the query part is the problem. While testing this against the sqlite in-memory db it does work.

What can be the problem when working against MySQL db with `pymysql` driver?

tried searching the web for 1 day for similar problems couldn't find even 1. My sqlalchemy version was 0.9.1 and I downgraded it to 0.9 and still the problem persists.

edit:
going in different approach, i tried writing a code that doesnt use the class mapping. this time i actually managed to retrieve the data in the db. i added the code

```
metadata = MetaData()
cpu = Table('cpu',metadata,
    Column('id',INTEGER,primary_key=True),
    Column('name',String(50))
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
q = select([cpu])
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute(q)
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

as i am not using the mapped class i created i thought id show the class itself, might give some insight:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column,INTEGER,String

class CpuTable(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'cpu'
    id = Column(INTEGER,primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<cpu(id = '%s',name = '%s')>" % (self.id,self.name)
```

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL database schema is in sync? Sounds like CpuTable.id doesn't have an actual column in database.

Comment: yes i am sure. CpuTable is the name of the class that represents the table "cpu". the table itself exists, and it has column "id" in it. thats what im talking about, it does exists, but the statement that executed inclues the "AS" directive, changing the cpu.id into cpu_id.

Comment: Odd indeed. Give mysql+mysqlconnector a shot just to be sure.

Comment: we hit this on the mailing list and the user needed to upgrade to the latest pymysql.

Comment: for some odd reason i posted here the solution (upgrading pymysql from .4 to .6) but answer didnt get posted

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments from [zzzeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726797/could-not-locate-column-in-row-for-column#comment32961426_21726797)) and the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987364/igal-kreimer) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726797/could-not-locate-column-in-row-for-column#comment32968186_21726797)) the problem was resolved by upgrading pymysql (from 0.4 to 0.6).

Answer (score -2):

```
for row in session.query(CpuTable).all():
    item = row['CpuTable']
    print(item.cpu_id,item.cpu_name)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.